# Where can I find a picture of the complete 9-map on a triple torus that corresponds to Heffter’s table?

Tags: graph-colorings, genus, colorings

What I’m looking for is the analogue of
[Figure 5 in the paper by Saul Stahl, The Othe Map Coloring Theorem, Mathematics Magazine 1985](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6vBq.jpg), which is a complete 8-map $M_8$ on the double torus $S_2$ that corresponds to Heffter’s table for n=8,
but for a complete 9-map $M_9$ on the triple torus $S_3$ that corresponds to the [table for n=9 in Heffter’s paper, Uber das Problem der Nachbargebiete, Math. Ann. 1891.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rKCe.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

OK, having received no answer, I drew one such map myself. Took me a while. From Heffter’s table of the adjacency pattern to the corresponding picture involving 22 triangles and 1 hexagon, then to the complete 9-graph on a decent representation of the triple torus, and finally to the complete 9-map on the usual drawing of the triple torus, there are so many steps where you can get confused. In case anyone is interested, my map can be found here [http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~benzoni/complete-9-map-triple-torus.pdf](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ebenzoni/complete-9-map-triple-torus.pdf). Do not hesitate to contact me if you have, or know of better drawings, or if you are interested in details of the construction.

Answer (score 3):

I have a small group of friends who have been playing with maps on higher genus surfaces. We have made Heffter’s M_9 out of fabric and a different M_9 in origami. We have also made crochet models and some drawings. My M_8 and M_9 in origami will be in the JMM Mathematical Art Exhibition in Boston in January. We will also be displaying 3 different fabric M_9 (including Heffter’s) during the Fiber Arts Session Exhibit on Jan. 4. Any chance you are coming to the JMM? Here is a link to my origami models:

http://gallery.bridgesmathart.org/exhibitions/2023-joint-mathematics-meetings/etorrenc